# ¿Cómo configurar hosting firebase?

Tags: nodejs, firebase, aplicación-web, npm, hosting

Tengo el siguiente problema, quiero usar las siguientes instrucciones para obtener lo necesario para hacer hosting, Implementar el sitio web

`firebase login firebase init`

antes de esta instrucción tuve que instalar firebase -tools y actualizar node.js y npm 

`npm install -g firebase-tools`

y me da este error

```
C:\Users\luis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\google-auto-auth\index.js:10
class Auth {
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\luis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\requireAuth.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Node.js está usando?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ayer me sucedió cuando intentaba hacer deploy de mi página a un Hosting Firebase y también arrojó un error, pero diferente. Sin embargo, una vez actualicé todos los paquetes npm, dejó de arrojar el error.

Podrías probar lo siguiente: `npm update` ó `npm update -g` para actualizar los paquetes globales y luego volver a intentarlo.

Adicionalmente, si estás usando Angular, asegúrate de que al hacer `ng build --prod` se crée correctamente la carpeta "dist", que es desde dónde se cargarán los archivos a Firebase.

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: si era la solución